# ESP32 custom board flashing not working

Tags: esp32, cp2102

I'm trying to build a custom microcontroller board based on the ESP32 chip (just the chip, not the WROOM module).

I've got to the point where all the power works and the USB to serial gets recognized. I'm now trying to flash the ESP, but the chip itself doesn't respond (the IDE tries to connect to it, but it just fails).

The connections on the PCB look fine, and the LEDs for the serial communication also blink when trying to flash it. I've already found and fixed two really stupid mistakes (VDD3p3_CPU not connected to VCC and VBUS to Vs which is connected to the USB), but it's still not working.

If anybody could take a look at it, it would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Terminal Output:

```
Processing esp32dev (platform: espressif32; board: esp32dev;         framework: arduino)
-------------------------------------------------------------------        ------------------------------------------------------------
Verbose mode can be enabled via `-v, --verbose` option
CONFIGURATION:     https://docs.platformio.org/page/boards/espressif32/esp32dev.html
PLATFORM: Espressif 32 (4.2.0) > Espressif ESP32 Dev Module
HARDWARE: ESP32 240MHz, 320KB RAM, 4MB Flash
DEBUG: Current (cmsis-dap) External (cmsis-dap, esp-prog, iot-bus-        jtag, jlink, minimodule, olimex-arm-usb-ocd, olimex-arm-usb-ocd-h,         olimex-arm-usb-tiny-h, olimex-jtag-tiny, tumpa)
PACKAGES:
 - framework-arduinoespressif32 @ 3.20002.220503 (2.0.2)
 - tool-esptoolpy @ 1.30300.0 (3.3.0)
 - tool-mkfatfs @ 2.0.1
 - tool-mklittlefs @ 1.203.210628 (2.3)
 - tool-mkspiffs @ 2.230.0 (2.30)
 - toolchain-xtensa-esp32 @ 8.4.0+2021r2-patch3
LDF: Library Dependency Finder -> 
LDF Modes: Finder ~ chain, Compatibility ~ soft
Found 32 compatible libraries
Scanning dependencies...
No dependencies
Building in release mode
Retrieving maximum program size .pio\build\esp32dev\firmware.elf
Checking size .pio\build\esp32dev\firmware.elf
Advanced Memory Usage is available via "PlatformIO Home > Project     Inspect"
RAM:   [          ]   4.9% (used 16148 bytes from 327680 bytes)
Flash: [==        ]  15.7% (used 206209 bytes from 1310720 bytes)
Configuring upload protocol...
AVAILABLE: cmsis-dap, esp-prog, espota, esptool, iot-bus-jtag,     jlink, minimodule, olimex-arm-usb-ocd, olimex-arm-usb-ocd-h, olimex-    arm-usb-tiny-h, olimex-jtag-tiny, tumpa
CURRENT: upload_protocol = esptool
Looking for upload port...
Auto-detected: COM3
Uploading .pio\build\esp32dev\firmware.bin
esptool.py v3.3
Serial port COM3
Connecting......................................   
A fatal error occurred: Failed to connect to ESP32: No serial data     received.
For troubleshooting steps visit:     https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esptool/en/latest/troubleshooting.h    tml
*** [upload] Error 2
================================================= [FAILED] Took 11.84 seconds =================================================
```

Comment: Did you pull down GPIO0 before attempting to flash, to get the ESP32 into programming mode?

Comment: @StarCat this should be done by the CP2102 chip and the npn tranisistors. In the internet there are a lot of truth tables for this stetup. Pls correct me if im wrong.

Comment: How are you invoking esptool.py? What's your command line look like? I assume you hooked up an external flash memory chip, not shown?

Comment: @vicatcu I added the schematic for the Flash memory. Do i need to upload some sort of bootloader on the flash or on the esp32 chip ? I've tried to upload a default project, just the setup() and loop() without anything in it using the PlatformIO extension(Module: Espressif ESP32 Dev Module).

Comment: please do not post pictures of text ... post the text itself ... some people here cannot view pictures